# csslint: how to exclude directories from command line?

Tags: csslint

I want to exclude all `vendor` directories (ex.: `public/css/vendor` ) using `csshint`, but when I run the following command:

```
csslint --format=lint-xml --exclude-list=/vendor/ /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/project/src > /home/user/Desktop/test.xml
```

nothing happens! Can anybody help me with this?

I got an example from here:

https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/command-line-interface

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was:

When u run the command u must specify the path in the exclude-list.

Example:

```
csslint --format=lint-xml --exclude-list=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/project/src/folder /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/project/src > /home/user/Desktop/test.xml.
```

I can't give him a pattern, only a file or dir with full path.